# Accessing google drive with tramp in emacs 25

Tags: tramp, emacs25

I'm trying to access my google drive from within emacs. According to [this](https://emacsnotes.wordpress.com/2018/07/08/your-google-drive-now-within-your-emacs/), that's possible with emacs 26. Based on the [tramp 2.4.3 manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/) I think that's because emacs 26 comes with version 2.4.3 of Tramp. True?

If so, does that mean that an alternative route to achive google drive access in emacs 25 is to update from Tramp 2.2.13 to Tramp 2.4.3?

If so, how do I do that? My `tramp-version` is 2.2.13.25.2. I tried installing tramp 2.4 via elpa, but still `tramp-version` returns 2.2.13.25.2. When I try `C-x C-f ~//gdrive:john.doe@gmail.com:/` I get the error

> Symbol’s function definition is void: tramp-compat-tramp-file-name-slots

This is a different error message than before I melpa-ed tramp; before it was "Unknown method "gdrive".

Note that I have successfully added my google drive to my GNOME desktop.

**EDIT** `tramp-version` is now showing 2.4.3.3. Now when I try `C-x C-f ~//gdrive:john.doe@gmail.com:/` I get the error

> Symbol’s function definition is void: "(setf
>   tramp-file-name-localname)"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Tramp 2.4.3 works with Emacs 25. It is not distributed via MELPA (to my knowledge), but via GNU ELPA. The recent version there is 2.4.3.3. Do you have installed it via the Emacs Package Manager?

If installed, there shall be a directory `~/.emacs.d/elpa/tramp-2.4.3.3`. This shall be taken into account when starting Emacs. If not, you shall add this to the beginning of your `load-path`, and restart Emacs.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I installed tramp via GNU elpa (when I said 'melpa', I meant 'GNU elpa'). The describe variable output for `load-path` shows "/home/quinn/.emacs.d/elpa/tramp-2.4.3.3". Now `tramp-version` does indeed show 2.4.3.3; this is somewhat mysterious but maybe I just hadn't restarted Emacs. Now when I try to run `C-x C-f ~//gdrive:john.doe@gmail.com:/` (where john.doe@gmail.com is replaced by my email, I get the error: Symbol’s function definition is void: "(setf tramp-file-name-localname)". Any idea about that?

Comment: Strange. What happens if you start `emacs -Q -L home/quinn/.emacs.d/elpa/tramp-2.4.3.3` ?

Comment: When I do that, emacs doesn't even have a `tramp-version` command at all intially. Then I try `C-x C-f ~//gdrive:john.doe@gmail.com:/` and get "Unknown method "gdrive" ". After that though, tramp`-version` does work and returns 2.2.13.25.2.

Comment: Well, debugging is out of scope of SX. Please write an email to `tramp-devel@gnu.org`, and well see.

Comment: OK, I will. Thanks. Is even the fact there's initially no `tramp-version` command unusual?

Comment: `tramp-version` is declared as soon as Tramp is loaded. But I don't want to debug here.

Comment: @QuinnCulver That command line should have been `emacs -Q -L /home/quinn/.emacs.d/elpa/tramp-2.4.3.3 -f package-initialize` (the path was missing a leading `/`, and `-Q` disables package initialization so without `package-initialize` the tramp package would be loadable but not autoloaded).